# Reference request: a guide through quantum probability

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, soft-question, stochastic-processes, quantum-mechanics

Could you point out a comprehensive reference book (or more than one, if it is the case) on *Quantum Probability* that introduces the subject and then gradually builds up to the edges of contemporary research?

Comment: Which particular flavour of QP? i.e. Hudson/Parthasarathy, or free probability (Voiculescu/Bercovici et al.)

Comment: I also think you need to set your sights lower at first. How much probability theory do you know? How much QM?

Comment: Dear @YemonChoi, for the first question: I don't know: that's why I'm searching for a comprehensive reference (or more than one references, if it is the case); for the second question: I've successfully completed my course "Probability theory and Stochastic Processes", but, being a math student, I don't know basically anything of QM yet and that's why I am searching for something that *introduces* the concepts (maybe in the appendices?) before building up [in any case, some revision of the concepts of probability in an appendix won't hurt].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in quantum probability from mathematical perspective, these two books will be helpful:

http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-3-540-60270-5 (Quantum Probability for Probabilists, by P.A. Meyer).

[http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Probability-Mathematical-Statistics/dp/0123053404](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123053404) (Quantum Probability (Probability and Mathematical Statistics), by S.P. Gudder).

This textbook is very good, but the focus is on quantum information and quantum computing:

[http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Computation-Information-Anniversary-Edition/dp/1107002176](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107002176) (Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, by Michael A. Nielsen and Isaac L. Chuang).

Comment: I've skimmed quickly through the second book you recommended, and it seems to be the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you very much, Professor. Of course, if any other reference comes to mind, please, don't hesitate to add it.

Comment: Check also Itamar Pitowsky's article "Quantum mechanics as a theory of probability" in http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F1-4020-4876-9_10

Answer (score 5):

These notes are excellent:

- Greg Kuperberg, *A concise introduction to quantum probability, quantum mechanics, and quantum computation*, 2005 ([pdf](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/intro-2005.pdf))

Comment: $+1$ This doesn't seem comprehensive, but looks very good. Thank you very much for the suggestion :).

Comment: Do you happen to know some other resources on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

I find the way

**Michael Dickson**. **1998**. *Quantum Chance and Nonlocality*. Cambridge University Press.

introduces the material very nicely and completely in the way you requested, in the first several chapters. It's quite comprehensive.